# Как получить класс по его наименованию (python 2.7)

Tags: python, классы

Как получить класс по его наименованию без использования словаря `classDict`, может есть какой нить "`get_class`"?

```
iUser = userClasses.iUser
iGroup = userClasses.iGroup

classDict = {'iUser': iUser, 'iGroup': iGroup}

@bottle.route('/list/<class_name>')
def list(class_name):
    classPoint = classDict[name]
    result = classPoint.getAllObject()
    return result
```

Comment: В общем случае это невозможно, а в частном не нужно, потому что уязвимость будет

Comment: @andreymal, какая уязвимость?

Comment: Открою какой-нибудь `/list/AdminAccount` или ещё что-нибудь нехорошее что найдётся

Comment: @andreymal Как это связано с вопросом? Разговор-то про классы. Что декоратор bottle.route я не в курсе, но что мешает программе просто открыть файл '/list/AdminAccount', если на то пошло?

Comment: @dzhioev я не понял о какой программе речь и при чём тут bottle.route, но блин, в любом случае я же смогу так получить всё содержимое AdminAccount'ов. Даже если сегодня такого класса нет, через полгода-годик активной разработки сами не заметите как подобных классов десятка два наберётся, а кто-нибудь типа меня потом взломает сайт через код, указанный в ответе :) Реально, я уже встречал один подобный случай.

Comment: Здесь код приведен в упрощенном виде, конечно же там будет стоять проверка на админа. =)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В первом приближении как-то так:

```
classPoint = globals()[name]
```

Встроенная функция [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) возвращает словарь имя->объект для всех объектов определенных в глобальном пространстве имен.

Answer (score 1):

```
klass = getattr(userClasses, class_name)
```